# Ajax PHP Form Submission with Image and Text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I'm writing an app that allows my wife to add her recipes to a database i have set up. I have a form set up with both text and a file input for an image. It works fine and she can upload text and image to the database. Now, I'm trying to add a feature so that she can edit it. It's the same exact form only the data goes to a different PHP file for processing. When she clicks the "Edit" button it populates all the text inputs with the data pulled from the server and she can edit. She can also add a new photo if she wishes. Despite the fact that it's the same form, it will not upload the image. The text uploads fine, but the `$_POST['recipeImage']` is always empty when I look at the object being sent to the server (`recipeImage: ""`);

I am baffled and cannot see why this isn't working. Here is the code:

**HTML FORM (IMAGE UPLOAD IS A BOTTOM):**

```
<div id="editRecipeModal">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
       <form action="../PHP/modify_recipe.php" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="editRecipeForm" name="editRecipeForm">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="" id="creatorIdEdit" name="creatorId">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="" id="recipeIdEdit" name="recipeId" value="">
                <div class="card-header card-header-text" data-background-color="purple">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><i class="far fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Edit Recipe</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content"
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Recipe Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" id="editRecipeName" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Prep Time</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="prepTime" id="editPrepTime" required>
                                <span class="help-block">Numbers Only. In minutes... ie: 120 Minutes</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Servings</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="servings" id="editServings" required>
                                <span class="help-block">Numbers Only...</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Calories</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="calories" id="editCalories" required>
                                <span class="help-block">Numbers Only</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Brief Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="editBriefDescription" rows="5" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Ingredients</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="ingredients" id="editPasteIngredientsShow" rows="20" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Recipe Steps</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="directions" id="editPasteStepsShow" rows="20" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">Search Tags</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                <label class="control-label"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="editTags" name="tags" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div><br> <br> <br> <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-3">
                                    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="vegOrVegan" data-size="7" id="vegOrVeganEditSelect">
                                                    <option disabled selected>Dietary Restrictions</option>
                                                    <option value="" name="">None</option>
                                                    <option value="T" name="T">Vegetarian</option>
                                                    <option value="VG" name="VG">Vegan</option>
                                                </select>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="vegOrVeganEdit" name="vegOrVegan">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-3">
                                    <select class="selectpicker" id="suggestedPairingEditSelect" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Suggested Pairing" data-size="7">
                                                    <option disabled selected>Suggested Pairing</option>
                                                    <option value="" name="">None</option>
                                                    <option value="B" name="B">Beer</option>
                                                    <option value="WW" name="WW">White Wine</option>
                                                    <option value="RW" name="RW">Red Wine</option>
                                                </select>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="suggestedPairingEdit" name="suggestedPairing" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-3">
                                    <select class="selectpicker" id="" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Some Other Attributes" data-size="7">
                                                    <option disabled selected>Some Other Attributes</option>
                                                    <option value="" name="">None</option>
                                                    <option value="B" name="B">Beer</option>
                                                    <option value="WW" name="WW">White Wine</option>
                                                    <option value="WW" name="WW">Red Wine</option>
                                       </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new text-center" data-provides="fileinput">
                                <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail">
                                    <img src="../assets/img/placeholder.jpg" alt="...">
                                </div>
                                <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="btn btn-rose btn-round btn-file">
                                                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span>
                                    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                                    <input type="file" name="recipeImage" id="recipeImageEdit" />
                                    </span>
                                    <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-danger btn-round fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style=" text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg modRecButton" type="submit" id="submitRecipe">Submit Changes</button></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 closePanel" style="text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;" id="closePanel"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Cancel Changes</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#editRecipeForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../PHP/modify_recipe.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                let newObject = parsedResponse[0]
                if (parsedResponse == 'notModified') {
                    showErrorModal();
                }else{
                    reBuildAfterObjectChange(newObject.recipeId, parsedResponse);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                showErrorModal();
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    include 'db_operations.php';
            if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['ingredients'])&& isset($_POST['directions']) && isset($_POST['suggestedPairing'])  && isset($_POST['prepTime']) && isset($_POST['servings']) && isset($_POST['calories'])  && isset($_POST['vegOrVegan']) && isset($_POST['recipeId']) && isset($_POST['creatorId']))
            {
        $result = '';
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];     
        $ingredients = str_replace(';', '-', $ingredients);
        $ingredients = str_replace('\n', ';', $ingredients);
        $directions = $_POST['directions'];
        $directions = str_replace(';', '-', $directions);
        $directions = str_replace('\n', ';', $directions);          
        $suggestedPairing = $_POST['suggestedPairing'];
        $prepTime = $_POST['prepTime'];
        $servings = $_POST['servings'];
        $calories = $_POST['calories'];
        $vegOrVegan = $_POST['vegOrVegan'];
        $recipeId = $_POST['recipeId'];
        $creatorId = $_POST['creatorId'];
        $tags = $_POST['tags'];
        $time=time();
        $lastModified = (date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time));

        modifyRecipe_recipes($name, $description, $ingredients, $directions, $suggestedPairing, $prepTime, $servings, $calories, $vegOrVegan, $lastModified, $creatorId, $recipeId, $tags);
            }

        if(isset($_POST['recipeImage'])){
            $size = $_FILES['recipeImage']['size'];

            if($size > 0){
             $tmp_dir = $_FILES["recipeImage"]["tmp_name"];
            $tmpImg = $_FILES['recipeImage']['name'];
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($tmpImg, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            $recipeImage = rand(10000, 10000000).".".$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, "../userRecipeImages/".$recipeImage);
            $sql = 'UPDATE recipes SET recipeImage = :recipeImage WHERE creatorId = :creatorId AND recipeId= :recipeId';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);       
            $stmt->bindParam(':creatorId', $creatorId, PDO::PARAM_STR);                       
            $stmt->bindParam(':recipeImage', $recipeImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);            
            $stmt->bindParam(':recipeId', $recipeId, PDO::PARAM_STR);            
            $stmt->execute();               

            }

        }


        $modifiedRecipeDate = getLastModified_recipes($lastModified, $creatorId);
        if ($modifiedRecipeDate === $lastModified) {
                $newObject = getSingleRecipeById_recipes($recipeId, $creatorId);
                echo json_encode($newObject);
        }
        else {
            $result = "notModified";
            echo json_encode($result);
        }


?>
```

Comment: you should find the file in the [$_FILES array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), not in `$_POST['recipeImage']`

Comment: you do it right later anyway, only the ` if(isset($_POST['recipeImage'])` is wrong

Comment: ..... Yep... hours of staring and it was something silly. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously forgot to change `$_POST['recipeImage']` to `$_FILES['recipeImage']`

Files are contained in the `$_FILES` global variable not `$_POST`

Change this

```
if(isset($_POST['recipeImage'])){
```

to

```
if(isset($_FILES['recipeImage'])){
```